# access powershell dataset data

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi Guys thanks for help really appreciate it.
Iam new to powershell, using powershell iam accessing data of sql server
my query is getting executed, but output of query is 10 that data is getting filled in dataset 
i want that data to be concatenated in path like 10, 20 in $version

```
$select=Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\'$version'\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt' #|Out-File c:\pattern.txt
```

Please find code below

```
param([string]$servername)

$filePath = "c:\temp\result.txt"



try
{

$SqlQuery = "select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0,CHARINDEX('.',convert(sysname,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0))"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Servername; Database = master; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$version = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].data

#$version=System.Data.DataSet.Tables[1].Rows[0][0] 
Write-Host $version
$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\temp\version.csv"
$defaultdata = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].data
Write-Host $defaultdata

$select=Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\'$version'\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt' #|Out-File c:\pattern.txt
$select1=Select-String -Pattern "Final result:" -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\'$version'\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt' |Out-File D:\temp\pattern.txt
write-host($select.Line.Length)

if( $select.Line.Length -gt 0 )
{
   Write-Host 'Contains String'
   $select2=Select-String -Pattern "Passed" -Path 'D:\temp\pattern.txt'

   if($select.Line.Length -gt 0)
   {  
    #out-File c:\temp\result.txt $filePath -Append 
    New-Item $filePath -ItemType file
    'Success'| Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append   
   }   
   else   
   {
    New-Item $filePath -ItemType file
    'Failed'| Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append  
   }      

}
else
{
   Write-Host 'Does not contain String'
}

}
catch

{
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White "Fail" 


        $errText =  $Error[0].ToString() 


            if ($errText.Contains("network-related")) 


        {Write-Host "Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall."}   

        Write-Host $errText 


        continue 

}
```

i want $version=10 as query has output 10, somehow iam not able to get it,
though iam getting same data in csv file but i want same data in $version variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a provlem when you call data there is no data column in the data set you can do two thing
1:
$version = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].data

Replace

$version = $DataSet.Tables[0].rows[0].Column1

or
2:
You can change the SQLquery and name the column you select like this:
$SqlQuery = "select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(sysname, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0,CHARINDEX('.',convert(sysname,SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),0)) as data"